# Remove Expired Certificates with Powershell

Tags: powershell, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, client-certificates

I have a simple script to show all certificates on a server, I would like to expand that script to then remove all expired certificates

I have tried several scripts from MS and 3rd parties to find a remove certs but have had no luck with them working properly

The first code I am using is:

**Get-ChildItem Cert:\ -Recurse**

This Powershell script shows all certificates on a server.

Example output is below for each certificate. I want to target the NotAfter field and have the script then remove the certificate if it's old than todays date

Subject:
Issuer:
Thumbprint:
FriendlyName:
NotBefore:
NotAfter:
Extensions

I would also like to do this for a list of servers, have the script run on each server in a text document, query all certificates, then remove the certs that are expired and move on to the next server.

I have seen some code targeting the date like the following:

**ForEach-Object -begin { $now = get-date } -process { if ($PSItem.NotAfter -lt $now ) { $PSItem } } | Remove-Item**

I would like the script to go out and query a servers certificates, then deletes out the expired certificates

Answer (score 8):

What you are after is this. This should work perfectly for you. You were close in your logic, just the execution seemed to be a bit off.

```
$ListOfServers = Get-Content "c:\temp\serv.txt"

Foreach($Server in $ListOfServers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {
        # Get Certificate list and assign to a variable
        $Certs = Get-ChildItem "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -Recurse

        # Loop through each object in $Certs
        Foreach($Cert in $Certs) {
            # If The objects property "NotAfter" is older than the current time, delete
            If($Cert.NotAfter -lt (Get-Date)) {
                $Cert | Remove-Item
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edited based on comment to prevent accidental destruction of all certs.

To get a list of all cert storage locations.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path "Cert:" -Recurse `
    | Where-Object {($_).GetType().Name -eq 'X509Store'}).Name
```

Comment: Note that you shall not execute the script outside of Personal (My) cert store. There is a number of expired CA certificates required by an operating system.

Comment: Good call. I have since edited the answer to ensure that only the `\My` certs are returned.

Comment: That worked great for the Certificates\Personal\Certificates, if I wanted to do the same in a different folder like Trusted Root Certification Authorities or any of the others, what name would I use in place of MY, is there a list that has the name of each of these that I can sub into the script? And thank you for taking the time to answer my question and share your knowledge I greatly appreciate it

Comment: @aztech I have added a little bit of a one-liner that will allow you to get the names of the cert stores.

Comment: that works perfect thank you. One last question, if I wanted to run the script against a group of servers listed on a text file how would I do that since it already has a foreach statement in it, I wasnt sure where to place another foreach statement

Comment: @crypt32 you mentioned not running this out of the MY location and that the OS still needs some expired certs, are those expired certs in a specific store? Where would I find them? I ask for education on my part

Comment: They are stored at least in trusted root CAs, 3rd party root CAs, intermediate CAs stores.

Comment: I am trying the following but when I run it from a server with elevated privileges in Powershell ISE it says completed but when I check the server I'm targeting the Personal store still shows expired:                                                     certs$serverlist = @("c:\temp\serv.txt")
Foreach ($Serv in $serverlist) {

$Certs = Get-ChildItem "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -Recurse

Foreach($Cert in $Certs) {
    # If The objects property "NotAfter" is older than the current time, delete
    If($Cert.NotAfter -lt (Get-Date)) {
        $Cert | Remove-Item
    }
}  
}

Comment: Updated code. I would recommend not running any of this code or at least running it past someone who knows what they are doing. Your comment showed that you are trying to run a foreach loop on a single string in an array and did not actually get the content from the text file.

Answer (score 0):

function Remove-expired-personal-certs {
Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My | ForEach-Object {if ($*.NotAfter -lt (Get-Date)) {Remove-Item -LiteralPath $*.pspath }}
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).